# HTML files have unwanted comments automatically added

Tags: html, sharepoint

We have noticed that HTML files SharePoint has unwanted comments added in the code.

Even after we delete the following comment and save the file, it gets added back after a few minutes:

> EW54V3QVCDWX-2103697601-166778
> d49d2304-f46e-4684-84df-1df7cb938cb5
> https://morningstaronline.sharepoint.com/sites/PPGCore/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=EW54V3QVCDWX-2...,
> EW54V3QVCDWX-2103697601-166778

Originally the commented code was below, but it changes to the one above after I try deleting and saving the file:

> Ruban
> Bajracharya
> 3787300.00000000
>
> Ruban
> Bajracharya
>
> 0x0101000A9B5D39DB216E45A020A630DDC3CB28 EW54V3QVCDWX-2103697601-166887
> 3ad54a47-d15d-4b62-a6ef-d76a8a83813a
> https://morningstaronline.sharepoint.com/sites/PPGCore/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=EW54V3QVCDWX-2...,
> EW54V3QVCDWX-2103697601-166887

Is there a way to disable Sharepoint/OneDrive from doing this?

Comment: What is the comment? Your question is hard to understand. What is the original and what is the change you don't want? Also, can you specify exactly what you are doing and where the code is added? What is the user interface involved? Visual Studio? A browser? A text editor? More information please. As a new user, please read this carefully: Edit your question to provide more details. Do NOT post details into a comment. You can post a comment when you have updated your question, so that followers of the question are alerted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem in Uploading, you may need to update credentials of One Drive. Your file may not be uploaded correctly. Or try updating through the web without the PC folder.